A question on embedding of group and group isomorphism.
I am confused about the following question, it looks obvious but turns out hard for me.
If group G can be embedded into another group H,
prove that there exists a group S that is isomorphic to H, such that G≤S.
(G can be embedded into H means there exists an isomorphism between G and a subgroup K of H.)
I tried to use the union of G and H\K to make S, and expand the isomorphism  between G and K to the one between H and S, but I met the difficulty defining the operation on that union when considering the possible existence of common elements of G and H\K.
I find the operation I defined does not satisfy the law of union properly and if there are common elements, the union may not be enough.
But if I make S without using H, it may be tough to define the isomorphism between S and H.
Perhaps my thinking is completely wrong.
How can S and the isomorphism between H and S be constructed? Or any other ways to solve it without construction?
Thank you for any assistance.

If you are worried about the possibility that the sets $G$ and $H \mid K$ are not disjoint, then step 1 would be to first find a group $H'$ and an isomorphism $H \mapsto H'$ such that $G$ and $H'$ are disjoint. This is a purely set theoretic issue.

The disjoint union $S=G\sqcup (H\smallsetminus K)$ is a good idea. I assume you realize there is a bijection $f:S\to H$. Use this bijection to define the group structure! In other words, define
$$s*s'=f^{-1}(f(s)*f(s')).$$
Because you have defined $f$ using the embedding $G\hookrightarrow H$ and inclusion $H\smallsetminus K\hookrightarrow H$, this successfully combines the group structures coming from $G$ and $H\smallsetminus K$ in the way you're hoping for.
What's left is to convince yourself this is actually a valid group law which makes $S\simeq H$, and to see that $G$ is a subgroup of $S$. A minor technical point here: make sure that the group law on $G$ is actually the restriction of the group law on $S$!

Perhaps taking the disjoint union of $G$ and $H \setminus K$ would be better, given the OP's expressed concern about the possibility that they are not disjoint to begin with.

You're blurring the lines between isomorphic and different groups.
I avoid doing this except in certain specific cases,  like different subgroups of the same group, for instance,  the four different Klein four subgroups of $S_4,$ or different Sylow subgroups of a given group. Or I guess if I were to dabble in representation theory.
Another way:
it suffices to find a non-trivial automorphism of $H.$
Any non-trivial group has a non-trivial automorphism.   See here.
